# vue-cli4 for multi-page use `indexPath`in `pages` config

Tags: vue-cli-4

I'm using `vue-cli4` for multi-page, and I want to be able to use `indexPath`in `pages` config. How to do that?

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use the **filename** key in **pages** object.

```js
module.exports = {
  outputDir: "custom_dist",
  pages: {
    admin: {
      entry: "src/admin/main.js",
      template: "src/admin/template.html",
      filename: "admin/index.html", // >> custom_dist/admin/index.html
   // filename: "../admin_dist/index.html", // >> admin_dist/index.html
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: This is it! I found it in the documentation `https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages` ,I was careless before,Thanks!